# How to get the data value and calculate in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, calculation

I have a table relating to the birth and deaths of each person. I created a JSON object nested in an array.

How to calculate the age of death of each person included in the data? 
I think I am not doing it properly

Also, what should I do to get the value in the data to calculate and display inside the table?

here is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

    let data = [{ // JSON Object nested in Array 
        "firstname": "Harold",
        "lastname": "Mullins",
        "birthdate": "07/04/1864",
        "deathdate": "09/11/1891"
    }, {
        "firstname": "Sarah",
        "lastname": "Houseman",
        "birthdate": "09/04/1864",
        "deathdate": "01/10/1876"
    }, {
        "firstname": "Alice",
        "lastname": "Davis",
        "birthdate": "11/12/1864",
        "deathdate": "04/10/1866"
    }, {
        "firstname": "Maud",
        "lastname": "Adams",
        "birthdate": "08/04/1864",
        "deathdate": "09/11/1908"
    }, {
        "firstname": "Seamus",
        "lastname": "O'Brien",
        "birthdate": "10/12/1864",
        "deathdate": "09/11/1901"
    }]


    let dataTable = $("<table><thead><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Born</th><th>Died</th><th>Age of Death</th></tr></thead></table>");
    $("body").append(dataTable.attr("class", "table")); // Create table skeleton and insert it into DOM. Add class for CSS styling 
    $.each(data, (index) => {
        dataTable.append(
            "<tr><td>" + data[index].firstname +
            "</td><td>" + data[index].lastname +
            "</td><td>" + data[index].birthdate + "m" +
            "</td><td>" + data[index].deathdate +
            "</td><td>" + data[index].ageofdeath
        );

        $("#censusdata").data('value');

        let dob = $('#censusdata').val();
        if (dob != '') {
            let today = new Date();
            let dayDiff = Math.ceil(today - dob) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
            let age = parseInt(dayDiff);
            $('#age').append((ageofdeath)(age + ' years old'));
        }

        let p = document.getElementById('averageageatdeath');

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
   <h1>Births and Deaths amongst Workhouse Residents - Born 1864</h1>
   <div id="censusdata"></div>
   <div id="averageageatdeath"></div>
</body>
```

I also tried this code right here to get the value of the dates for the calculation.

```js
$.each(data, (index) => {

data[index].birthdate + "m" +
data[index].deathdate +
data[index].ageofdeath
}
```

Comment: The line `$("#censusdata").data('value');` does absolutely nothing, and `$('#censusdata').val();` will return an empty string. But there's no need to do this anyway, even if it worked. You already have access to the DOB for each table row: `data[index].birthdate`. The next step is to somehow parse it into a date you can work with. (also, your data is an Array of Objects. There's no JSON in your code. JOSN is text)

Comment: ah cool. so I can access the elements using that. Do you have any idea how to calculate the age of death and display into the data.[index]ageofdeath?

Comment: The key is to calculate the age for each person, _then_ put it in the table row:https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/zf4mgtpo/

Comment: thank you a lot. whats a good way to break the code into separate functions?

Comment: I updated my fiddle to show one way of refactoring things.

Answer (score 0):

You could put this after you declare your data variable:

```js
data = data.map(person => {
  const ageofdeath = Math.floor((new Date(person.deathdate) - new Date(person.birthdate)) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365));
  return {
    ...person,
    ageofdeath
  }
});
```

Then access it with `data[index].ageofdeath`.

To be more efficient, put the calculation inside the jquery each loop before `dataTable.append`:

```js
const ageOfDeathInMilliseconds = new Date(data[index].deathdate) - new Date(data[index].birthdate);
data[index].ageofdeath = Math.floor(ageOfDeathInMilliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365));
```

Comment: Thank a lot. The calculation works well here but the first element of the array (Harold Mullins) for some reason shows undefined.

Comment: @user12700367 You need to do this *before* displaying the table / your $.each loop.

Comment: To be more efficient, yes put it on the first line inside the jquery each loop `data[index].ageofdeath = Math.floor((new Date(data[index].deathdate) - new Date(data[index].birthdate)) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365));`.  Might want to separate that into multiple lines

Comment: @user12700367 I get all numbers with that data, maybe a typo somwhere?

Comment: thank you. whats a good way to break this code into separate functions?

Comment: You could use a utility function for your milliseconds to years `const msToYrs = (ms) => Math.floor(ms / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365));` and another for getting the millisecond difference `const dateDiffInMs = (startDate, endDate) => new Date(endDate) - new Date(startDate);` then combine those two functions into a general function called `calcAgeOfDeath` or something like that.